# Why can chi squared not be used when the two variables are measured with means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I am taking an introductory to statistics class and I have found most of it to be pretty easy, but there is one thing I do not quite understand. The problem is given like this: There are two different types of nut mixes that a company produces: Deluxe and Premium. A group of researchers suspect that they are the same mix of nuts and so they take a sample of 20 pounds of each type of nut mix and record the data by type of nut: Brazil Nut, Almond, Cashew, Pecan, and Type of mix: Delixe or Premium. I understand that it is a chi square test for homogeneity and I also know that categorical data should be recorded as counts, but what happens when you record the data as pounds of nuts instead of number of nuts that causes a chi square test to be inapplicable?